# Is there already a simple language and parser to embed logic within XML?

Tags: xml, parsing

I have an XML representation of a survey that is to be rendered on multiple platforms with code written in multiple languages. I'd like to embed some simple logic in the XML to describe how questions should be skipped in a survey - and possibly more complicated rules later. For example, "if the answer to question 5 is 'Y', skip to question 10". The embedded language would need to be parsed in multiple languages. Is there already an established way to do this or would it be easier to create my own language and parser?

Comment: Have you looked into XAML?

Comment: There are lots of methods.  I like using Visual Studio (C# or Vb.net) and using XML Linq.

Comment: @Chris Williams You might want to look into the [IMS Global Question and Test Interop](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/) standard. It defines an XML schema for assessments/tests/surveys.

Answer (score 1):

XML is just an information carrier.  You decide what information, and how to break it up into (nested) chunks.   It isn't proactive in any sense.

If you want to "include" logic in XML to control how it is processed, you can pick any programming language you like, and include a chunk of it in an XML chunk you have designated for that purpose.  Then whatever recipient is supposed to process that XML, can, by convention, display it as it pleases, and run the code chunk (usually by something like an "eval" mechanism, which likely limits your choice of language) to provide custom behavior.

But there isn't any magic.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot of what you want can probably be achieved with XForms. It's certainly up to the task of displaying or hiding particular questions based on the answer to other questions.